# How to check whether data is written in csv file using Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv

I am trying to write data into a CSV file using Spring Boot controller. But the data is not written the file.

I've tried with debugging but I couldn't find out which attribute I should look for.
When debugging, I noticed in Stream Encoder,
isOpen = true, writebuffer = null, ch = null, haveLeftoverChar = false, leftoverChar = '\u0000' 0, lcb = null

I got my data which I wished to get, perfectly right.

Here is my code:

```
    FileWriter pw=null;
    try {
        pw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\all\\engine\\src\\main\\resources\\cases.csv", true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        pw.write("Registration Number: " + studentCase.getRegistrationNumber());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Do I have any mistakes in my controller code? and which attribute I should check to get to know whether the data is being written to the file or not?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I have any mistakes in my controller code?

**Yes**

Your horrendous exception handling. Do not catch exceptions, then proceed as-if nothing went wrong. Something is likely going wrong and you're ignoring it.

If you check the output from the `e.printStackTrace()` calls, you will likely see that, but do you even know where that output goes?

Also, you should use try-with-resources. It was added in Java 7, so nobody should write code like that, not using it.

On a side note, you don't need to call `flush()`, since the `close()` method will do that for you.

So try this:

```
String filename = "C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\all\\engine\\src\\main\\resources\\cases.csv";
try (FileWriter pw = new FileWriter(filename, true)) {
    pw.write("Registration Number: " + studentCase.getRegistrationNumber());
}
```

Then add `throws IOException` to the Spring MVC controller method.

Oh, and there is no need to check if something was written. If the code reaches the next statement after the end of the `try` block, then something was written. That is now guaranteed, since you no longer ignore exceptions.